# How do I escape HTML for th:errors?

Tags: thymeleaf

Let's say I have:

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" class="color--error" th:errors="*{firstName}"></span>
```

How do I escape the text if the error text contains HTML?  I know for normal text, we can use `th:utext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `3.0.8-SNAPSHOT`, Thymeleaf-Spring has `th:uerrors`.

See this GitHub issue for the discussion: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/153

And this change log for 3.0.8: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Thymeleaf-3-0-8-JUST-PUBLISHED-td4030687.html

Answer (score 2):

[`th:errors` is just a shortcut](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#field-errors).   You still use `th:utext` for this, you just have to manually output your errors.  In your case, the code could look something like:

```
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:each="err: ${#fields.errors('firstName')}" th:utext="${err}" class="color--error" />
```

Comment: ok, thanks - I was hoping for a similar shortcut like `th:uerrors` or something to that effect.